# Allocate more space for root partition on CentOS

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have a problem, I have a 2TB drive but for some reason 1.7TB is put into

```
/dev/sda2 1.8T 68M 1.7T 1% /home
```

I need to enlarge my root partition because now it's full and MySQL can't run because of this.

```
 Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /
/dev/root             9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /
devtmpfs               12G  400K   12G   1% /dev
/dev/sda2             1.8T   68M  1.7T   1% /home
tmpfs                  12G     0   12G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/root             9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named
/dev/root             9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/var/named
/dev/root             9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
/dev/root             9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.rfc1912.zones
/dev/root             9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key
/dev/root             9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind
/dev/root             9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.iscdlv.key
/dev/root             9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.root.key
```

Can someone help me to utilize disk space of `/dev/sda2` for `/dev/root`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the partitions using a liveCD for example. You will need to shrink the sda2 partition and expand the sda1. Any Live CD normally include a Partitioning (normally GParted). You must shutdown your system and do this.